# If there are two sub groups with orders that are co prime, show the intersection of the groups is the idenity element.

Tags: group-theory

Given H and K are sub groups of a finite group G and |H| is coprime to |K| show:
$ H \cap K = \{e\} $

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's theorem? What possible orders could an element have that is common to $H$ and $K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Given $h\in H$, we know the order of $h$, say $d$, divides $|G|$, since $H< G$. But similarly for $k\in K$. Now what does this say about any $x\in H\cap K$?

Comment: for some x | $x\in H\cap K$ o(x) | |H| ; o(x) | |K| ; o(x) | |G| and since |H| | |G| & |K| | |G| -> o(x) = 1 -> x=e and only e?

Comment: @MitchHughes Yessir! :)

Comment: man oh man, look at a question for 30 mins and get no where, some one gives you a nudge in the right direction and its the simplest thing. Thanks.

Comment: @MitchHughes Don't worry about, happens to everyone!